# Cursor keeps on flashing for a macro that runs every second

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code that updates a cell value every second.

```
Sub showtimer()
If CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 3).Value) = "0" Then
    Call startpostprocess
    Exit Sub
End If
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 3).Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    timetimer = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime timetimer, "showtimer", , True
End Sub
```

Cursor keeps on flashing/shows the blue processing cursor.
How can it be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

:Put

```
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```

As the first line in your sub. At least this works when you do something like:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
For i = 1 To 100000
    Debug.Print i 'to chew up time
Next i
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

When this is launched from the developer's tab in Excel the cursor looks normal even though it is running. I haven't tested it with your set-up of launching the sub every second (which might cause some flicker perhaps).

On Edit: I tested the situation where the sub is called every second and see that there is still a flicker. The problem is that the change to `Application.Cursor` doesn't persist past the function call. So in your case you aren't seeing the blue processing cursor (at least I don't see it) but you are seeing the cursor resetting every second, which is just as annoying.

Here is a potential work-around. Your code seems to be a count-down in cell C1. When the countdown reaches 0 the sub `startpostprocess` is launched. Presumably you did it the way that you did (calling `showtimer` every second) since you wanted Excel to be usable during the countdown. One way to achieve that is to have a `Countdown` sub run continuously during the countdown (so its change to the cursor doesn't go out of scope) and use `DoEvents` to keep Excel responsive:

```
Sub Countdown(n As Long)
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    Dim start As Double

    Do While n >= 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 3).Value = n
        start = Timer()
        Do While Timer < start + 1
            DoEvents
        Loop
        n = n - 1
    Loop
    startpostprocess
End Sub

Sub StartCountDown()
    Countdown ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convergence_Plot").Cells(1, 3).Value
End Sub
```

I changed the time value in cell C1 to a simple integer counter. When I put 10 in C1 and invoke `StartCountDown` the cell is changes to 10, 9, 8, ...,1, 0 at 1 second increments and then `startpostprocess` (I created a stub for it which just pops up a msgbox) launches. Cells can be edited during the countdown.

Comment: cursor still flashes. Is changing value of a cell cause behind this?

Comment: @Kartiki I see the problem. Hopefully the workaround in the edit could work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Application.Cursor = 1
```

It will lock your cursor in the default setting.
It isn't the best solution, but it stops the flashing.